# Excel VBA multiple double click actions

Tags: excel, vba, double-click

I've got some code that increments the date in a cell by 1 day when I double click it. But to repeat, I first have to click outside the cell.

Is it not possible to have multiple successive double click actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's where the `Cancel` in `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)` comes in.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Rem: Increment your date

    Cancel = True   '<-- Set to true

End Sub
```

If you only want to cancel in column B because that's where your dates are located, then:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Rem: Only Cancel if double-clicked in column B
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then

        Cancel = True   '<-- Set to true

    End If

End Sub
```